# neo4j cypher : how to query a linked list

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm having a bit of trouble to design a cypher query.

I have a graph data structures that records some data in time, using

```
(starting_node)-[:last]->(data1)-[:previous]->(data2)-[:previous]->(data3)->...
```

Each of the data nodes has a date, and some data as attributes that I want to sum.

Now, for the sake of the example, let's say I want to query what happened last week.
The closer I got is to query something like

```
start n= ... // definition of the many starting nodes here
match n-[:last]->d1, path = d1-[:previous*0..7]->dn
where dn.date > some_date_a_week_ago
```

Unfortunately, as I get the right path, I also get all the intermediate paths (from 2 days ago, from 3 days ago...etc).

Since there is many starting nodes, and thus many possible path lengths, I cannot ask for the longest path in my query. Furthermore, `dn.date` can be different from `date_a_week_ago` ( if there is only one data node this week, and one data node last month, then the expected path is of length=1).

Any tip on how to filter the intermediate paths in my query ?

Thanks in advance !

ps  : by the way, I'm quite new with the graph modeling, and I'd be interested with any answer that would require to change the graph structure if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a further point "dnnext" in your path, and add a condition to ensure the "dn" is the last one that satisfis the condifition,

```
start n= ... // definition of the many starting nodes here
match n-[:last]->d1, path = d1-[:previous*0..7]->dn-[:previous*0..1]->dnnext
where dn.date > some_date_a_week_ago and dnnext < some_date_a_week
```